# Importing an eclipse project in android studio giving problems

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am trying to import an eclipse android project in android studio but it is giving me following errors. Please give me the solution as I am not able to understand the reason behind the errors and the solution suggested:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:main:generateDebugSources, :main:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :gunAlert:generateDebugSources, :gunAlert:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :ffmpeg4android_lib:generateDebugSources, :ffmpeg4android_lib:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
:main:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:main:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:main:checkDebugManifest
:main:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:main:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:main:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:main:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71800Library
:main:prepareDebugDependencies
:main:compileDebugAidl
:main:compileDebugRenderscript
:main:generateDebugBuildConfig
:main:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:main:mergeDebugAssets
:main:generateDebugResValues
:main:generateDebugResources
:main:mergeDebugResources
:main:processDebugManifest
:main:processDebugResources
:main:generateDebugSources
:main:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:main:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:main:compileLint
:main:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:main:mergeDebugProguardFiles
:main:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:main:compileDebugJava
:main:packageDebugJar
:main:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:main:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:main:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:main:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:main:packageDebugResources
:main:bundleDebug
:main:compileDebugSources
:main:assembleDebug
:main:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
/home/vipulbansal/Desktop/Projects/GunAlert5/main/build/intermediates/manifests/tmp/manifestMerger2276692237948654021.xml
Error:(5, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 7 declared in library /home/vipulbansal/Desktop/Projects/GunAlert5/main/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage
Error:Execution failed for task ':main:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 7 declared in library /home/vipulbansal/Desktop/Projects/GunAlert5/main/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/18.0.0/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.63 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Have you read the error messages? They are quite explanatory...

Comment: I have. where to use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" ?

Comment: Add this attribute in the xml element (maybe the <application > in the mainfest) the error message is reporting. `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

Comment: Which versions of the SDK and Android Support Libraries are you using? Maybe you are using an obsolete version of the Android support libraries. Open up the SDK manager and update to latest version... Just a guess...

Comment: Now, after doin all it is giving me erros in appcompat v7

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the **app-compat** library in your project,
**you have to use a minSdkVersion >=7**, because the app-compat has minSdk = 7.

In your `build.gradl`e you have to declare the minSdk.
If not present, **the default value is 1**, and it is the reason of your issue.

In your build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion XX
    buildToolsVersion "XX.X.X"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7  //or more

        applicationId "xxxxxx"            
        targetSdkVersion XX
        versionCode X
        versionName "XX"
    }

}
```